# How to whitelist internal proxy and some external ip address in tomcat

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, load-balancing, whitelist

I am trying to whitelist internal users of our VPN network, and some external users accessing our site.

Our application workflow:
`Client (Request) -> F5/Load Balancer (IP address) -> Tomcat -> F5/Load Balancer -> Client`

**Note** F5 passes actual client ip address in x-forwarded-for

1.When i tried to change in server.xml with the below code changes, i could able to block external ip addresses accessing the site (other than the below allowed ip).

`<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve" 
allow="client-ip-add1|client-ip-add2" denyStatus="404" />`

2.But i could not able to allow the internal users of our VPN network connect to site with the VPN ip address.

```
 <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve"
 internalProxies="internal-VPN-ip-address" 
 remoteIpHeader="x-forwarded-for" 
 proxiesHeader="x-forwarded-by" 
 trustedProxies="internal-VPN-ip-address" />
```

Please help me identify the missing part here.